# Is it possible to define a No SQL model for spatial data?

Tags: spatial-database, sql, nosql, datastructure

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any way I can use a Key-Value store for geospatial data?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/59/is-there-any-way-i-can-use-a-key-value-store-for-geospatial-data)

I read somewhere about No SQL being a solution for large databases management, the kind that google uses for their operations, are there any examples of a spatial model data with NO SQL?

Comment: It might be helpful to clarify your title to be closer to your question, which is pointing to examples of NoSQL for spatial data management. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

While it isn't specifically addressing examples, the [Using Key-Value Stores for Geospatial Data](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/59/is-there-any-way-i-can-use-a-key-value-store-for-geospatial-data) question has a number of examples listed, along with a few ideas about how to implement it for your own needs.

This is certainly an emerging area of interest, a few upcoming talks from the [FOSS4G conference](http://2010.foss4g.org):

- [GeoCouch: A Spatial Index for CouchDB](http://2010.foss4g.org/presentations_show.php%3Fid=3048.html)
- [Geospatial Indexing with MongoDB](http://2010.foss4g.org/presentations_show.php%3Fid=3042.html)
- [Beyond PostGIS](http://2010.foss4g.org/presentations_show.php%3Fid=3173.html)
- [Distributed Spatial Indexing in the Cloud](http://2010.foss4g.org/presentations_show.php%3Fid=3584.html)

Comment: if there is a question which appears to be a duplicate, you can vote to close it; keeps things cleaner.  Also, since we have few users over 500, may need a mod flag to get it actually closed.

Comment: I answered it because it did seem to be a slightly different question, but I agree that they are quite close to one another. If this is just a list of examples, then it could be community wiki and coexist with the other page. If its asking the same thing as the other question, we should close it entirely.